# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php

the page code is all html and it wont load bec. of this error:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context line 142

code:

```
<div>
    <div class="">
        <input type="text" id="select_shelves" name="select_shelves" class="shelves_select_and_buttons" />
        <div id="shelves_menu" >
            <ul>
                <li id="li_" onclick="printValue();">option5 <= line 142 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <input type="button" onclick="dropShelves();" id="Shelves_select_button" name="Shelves_select_button" value="" class="grey_button"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are those functions PHP?

Comment: Is this really php, this just looks like html + javascript

Comment: I don't think the question is clear enough as you posted it. Also why did you tag the question PHP? Wouldn't HTML and Javascript be more suitable?

Comment: The error is thrown by doing something like `foo() = 'something'`.  Perhaps you're comparing with `=` instead of `==`...?

Comment: What are you trying to do with those edits? Please use the comment system to explain your question.

Comment: this question seems to be php related, but no php code is provided.

Answer (score 32):

If there is some PHP behind, the problem could be calling a function empty($var) in this way:

```
if(empty($var = getMyVar())) { ... }
```

Instead of this You should call it this way:

```
$var = getMyVar();
if(empty($var)) { ... }
```

Or better (as **deceze** has pointed out)

```
if(!getMyVar()) { ... }
```

Problem causes also other similar functions (isset, is_a, is_null, etc).

Comment: Again, this will not throw the *Can't use function return value in write context* (on 5.3, it'll throw a syntax error)...

Comment: there is  no php code just html

Comment: @bm2001: if there is only HTML code, what is throwing you that error??? and why did you tag the question PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532693/weird-php-error-cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context

Comment: Just do `if (!getMyVar())`. No `empty` needed at all.

Comment: @deceze We are only supposing there is similar construct based on the error message from OP. Do not see nothing wrong with my answer, so why -1?

Comment: Because `$var = func(); if (empty($var))` is a misuse of `empty`, you should use `if (!func())` or `if (!$var)` or `if (($var = func()) == false)` instead. See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Comment: So tomorow I will write some guide after reading which You will give another users -1? Misuse of `empty`... Where did You find this 'construct' within the guide?

Answer (score 14):

you are probably using something like:

```
if(empty(urFunc($foo)){
    ....
}
```

which won't work.

what ever it is (look for the lien number in the error to locate it) change it to:

```
$foo = urFunc($bar);
if(empty($foo)){
    ....
}
```

that should fix it.

Comment: That will not generate that error.  The error you'd get would be different (there would be an error though)...

Comment: erm... I was fairly sure it that it will (http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/fatal-error-can-t-use-method-return-value-in-write-383832.html)

Comment: I would suggest to reply to @ircmaxell like this since otherwise he won't get notified I think...

Comment: @AnonymousLoozah: I don't agree, given answers without a good enough context can be harmful for future users, besides I would not recommend using the up-vote for trying rather I would use it for gave the correct answer.

Comment: What you really want is `if (!urFunc($bar))`. No `empty` needed at all.

Comment: Why would this make for an error? Imagine urFunc() returns a string, why not use empty() to check whether the string is ""?

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php - priorto 5.5 you could only use it on variables.

Comment: @IanWood great! that's good to know!