# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, fatal-error

I've spent some time searching on the Internet and playing around with my code but I still can't figure out why I am getting this error message. 
Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
    } else {
        if (!empty($errors) && nexus_error($nexus)==false) {
            $message = "There were" . count($errors) . " errors in the form.";
        } if (!empty($errors) && nexus_error($nexus)) {
            $message = "There were" . count($errors) . " errors in the form.";
            $message .= "A user with the username" . $nexus . " already exists in the database."; 
        } if (empty($errors) && nexus_error($nexus)) { //***this line causes the error
            $message = "A user with the username" . $nexus . " already exists in the database."; 
        }
    }
```

The function nexus_error, by the way, is defined below:

```
function nexus_error($sel_nexus) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE nexus={$sel_nexus}";
    $result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($result_set);
    if (count(mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) != 0) {
        return true;    // bad
    } else {
        return false;  
    }
}
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Did you try [searching](http://www.google.com/search?q=Fatal+error%3A+Can't+use+function+return+value+in+write+context)?  Or looking at any of those **Related** questions that Stack Overflow suggested when you composed your question (they're listed again on the right of this page)?  The top hit on Google is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532693/weird-php-error-cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context) Stack Overflow question.

Comment: where is the function definition of confirm_query($result_setuery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Samy said the line in question is `if (count(mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) != 0) {`

The proper way to count the amount of results returned is  `mysql_num_rows()` instead of counting, and your line could simply be this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result_set) != 0) {
```

Also, your code is currently inefficient in that the `nexus_error($nexus)` *could be* called 3 times on the same variable if it filters through to the last `if` statement (that's 2 unecessary queries), consider refactoring like so:

```
$nexusError = nexus_error($nexus);
 } else {
    if (!empty($errors) && $nexusError ==false) {
        $message = "There were" . count($errors) . " errors in the form.";
    } if (!empty($errors) && $nexusError) {
        $message = "There were" . count($errors) . " errors in the form.";
        $message .= "A user with the username" . $nexus . " already exists in the database."; 
    } if (empty($errors) && $nexusError) { //***this line causes the error
        $message = "A user with the username" . $nexus . " already exists in the database."; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I took (both of) your suggestions. However, the error still persists. The error log is only showing me this one error. It is weird, even when I comment out the entire block of code, I still get the same error...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that;  do you mean that the error is in a different part of my code which I did not post?

Comment: Yeah it could be if you are getting the error when you uncomment it.

Comment: You are right; it was something really stupid (renamed file but was playing with code in original file). Thanks for the great answer

Answer (score 2):

```
if (count(mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) != 0)
```

You can't `count()` a function return's value. You should store it in a variable before.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I fixed that but the problem still remains, unfortunately

Comment: @SamyDindane Sorry, I am not sure what that is :S

Comment: @NVidovic All the lines that PHP have been through before it arrives to where your error is. You can enable Xdebug to see it.

Comment: great, I'll do that for next time. Thanks for the help :)