# Why this expression return error and how can I resolve?

Tags: php

This code:

```
if(!empty(trim($_POST['post']))){ }
```

return this error:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in ...

How can I resolve and avoid to do 2 checks ( trim and then empty ) ?

I want to check if POST is not only a blank space.

Comment: Did you actually read [the documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)? It clearly states that only variables work with `empty()` in PHP < 5.5

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2173318/561731

Comment: I want to check if POST is not only a blank space.

Comment: Why not just `trim($_POST['post']) !== ""`? `trim` `$_POST` values can only be strings, and `trim` will cast to string anyway.

Comment: @OneTrickPony the funniest thing is what sample in warning use exact trim function to display problem:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) it actually explains this problem specifically, then gives you an alternate solution. You can use

```
trim($name) == false.
```

Comment: Quite why the PHP documentation even recommends this solution is beyond me. Why promote unnecessary type coercion? (I'm not saying it's slower, but it's the principle of the matter!)

Comment: I'm not sure, but it is the shortest solution.

Comment: `!trim($name)` is shorter :-) And for that matter, so is `trim($name) === ''`!

Answer (score 3):

you cant use functions inside `isset` , `empty` statements. just assign the result of trim to a variable.

```
$r = trim($_POST['blop']);

if(!empty($r))....
```

edit: Prior to PHP 5.5

Answer (score 2):

```
if (trim($_POST['post'])) {
```

Is functionally equivalent to what you appear to be trying to do. There's no need to call `!empty`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (trim($_POST['post']) !== "") {
    // this is the same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, functions `isset()` and `empty()` are ment to **test variables**.

That means this

```
if(empty("someText")) { ... }
```

or this

```
if(isset(somefunction(args))) { ... }
```

doesn't make any sence, since result of a function is always defined, e.t.c.

These functions serve to tell wether a variable is defined or not, so argument must me a variable, or array with index, then it checks the index (works on objects too), like

```
if(!empty($_POST["mydata"])) {
    //do something
} else {
    echo "Wrong input";
}
```