# error in returning an array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, return

I am trying to return any array from function and its giving me following error

> Can't use function return value in write context

**This is the function :**

```
public function chekusername($username){  
        $error[0] = false;
        $error[1] = 'please enter a username';
        if(empty(trim($username))) return $error;
        $where = array(array('username','=',$username));      
        $result=$this->model->selectwhere($this->model->gettablename(),$where);
        $error[1] = 'username already exist try different username';
        $success[0] = true;
        if(empty($result)) return $success; else return $error;
    }
```

I am getting error on this line

```
if(empty(trim($username))) return $error;
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2173318/3574819

Comment: Could be that not the mentioned line is the problem, but the line in which you call your function checkusername().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else
>   will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not
>   work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

You have to split like following:

```
$trimUsername = trim($username);

if(empty($trimUsername)) return $error;
```

Also you can use this format:

```
if(trim($username) == false) return $error;
```