# Why $this->Html not defined but $this->html in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.X latest. Facing unique error.

This is error i am getting:

> Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object
>   [CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php, line 132]
>
> Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object
>   [CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php, line 132]
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function link() on a non-object in
>   /data/html/savaganza/app/View/Elements/header.ctp on line 21

I am simply using Html in my `header` element

```
Line 21: <?php echo $this->Html->link('Categories', array('controller'=>'categories') ); ?>
```

This `Header` element is calling from all views this is giving me error for some view, i don't know why but its working fine for some views.

### Efforts:

- When i change `$this->Html` to `$this->html` it works why???
- When i tried `var_dump($this->Html)` it gives `string(58)
  "�H��`.

Its working in my loacal server but not in live server.

Suggest me please.

Comment: It works because variables/objects/methods are case sensitive. Html is not the same thing as html.

Comment: But why `Html` working for some views?

Comment: It seems to me, that you have Html and html defined in different places, I would search for them in your code separately. Also, based on the output from `var_dump($this->Html);` seems the encoding/charset is differing somewhere.

Comment: I haven't defined `Html` or `html`. and its working on local also

Comment: you say that `$this->Html` works for some views and not for others. It's just a guess but maybe it works for some controllers and not for others. Are you sure you are calling your helper the right way in every controller?

Comment: @arilia i am sure i am calling helper form every controller.

Comment: can you post the other lines where `Html` works? And ca you please post the line in the controller where you set the helpers, and also the line in the AppController where you set the helpers?

Answer (score -1):

May be this question link to [Weird PHP error: 'Can't use function return value in write context'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532693/weird-php-error-cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context)

[Perfect Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2173318/2236219): Because empty is not a function but a language construct (not sure), and it only takes variable

but when i change this line:

```
$des = (!empty(html_entity_decode($c['Coupon']['description'])))?html_entity_decode($c['Coupon']['description']):'Not Avaliable';
```

to

```
$des = html_entity_decode($c['Coupon']['description']);
$des = (!empty($des)) ? $des : 'Not Avaliable';
```

It works i don't know exact reason. Hope somebody help me to understand this.

Comment: I think this is helpful for other. can't place too much text in comment, it'll hard to understand. Its answer because it solve my issue, i think this is what answer mean @arilia

Comment: @arilia you are not understanding my situation. So you can keep away from this. Thanks. I got my solution already