# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in [filter_input]

Tags: php, if-statement, fatal-error, filter-input

I'm learning PHP and have problem with I think `filter_input` function.

```
<?php


if (!isSet(filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, 'nazwa')) && !isSet(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nazwa')))
{
    include ("header.html");
    include 'form.html';
    include 'footer.html';
}
else if (isset(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nazwa'))) {
    setcookie("nazwa", (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nazwa')), time() + 60*60*24*365);
    include 'header.html';
    echo "<p> Dziękujemy za podanie danych.</p>";
    include 'footer.html';
}
else {
    include 'header.html';
    echo "Witamy, zostałeś rozpoznany jako {filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, 'nazwa')}.";
    include 'footer.html';
}

?>
```

I got:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in     C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject3\cookie\index.php on line 4

Could you plese help me?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532693/weird-php-error-cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context

Comment: Thank you Maximus2012, your tip helped me.

Answer (score 3):

You are using

```
isset(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nazwa')
```

Instead, you could use something like this (everywhere you call `isset()`):

```
$func = filter_input(INPUT_COOKIE, 'nazwa');
isset($func)
```

Directly from [php documentation](http://php.net/isset)

> Warning
>   isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function.

`isset()` is a language construct. Not a normal function.

Comment: i got worng from this `elseif(mysqli_num_rows($res_kode_ok)>0 && mysqli_num_rows($res_kurir)=0){`. so, how to fix it?

Comment: you may want to use `==` instead of `='. Also, show the code segment and describe the error. It's better if you post a separate question

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `isset()` on the result of a function call, here `filter_input()`.

Pull the `filter_input()` call out (assign return value of function to variable and then check it)

```
$nazwa = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nazwa');
if($nazwa) { ... }
```

or inline it:

```
if ($nazwa = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nazwa'))
{
    // your code
} else {
    echo 'Nope';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jens - this is it I didn't found.