# Moved WP to another domain -> Can't use function return value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am moving a Wordpress site to another domain, and one of the errors that has stopped the prosess is the following:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in
>   /home/spectrapride/public_html/wp-content/themes/spectranorge/single-4.php
>   on line 28

I have tried searching it up, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

**Here is my PHP, starting from line 27:**

```
<div class="col-md-6 videowidth">
    <?php if(!empty(types_render_field('embedded-media-field', array('raw'=>'true')))){?>
    <a id="teksttilvideo" onclick="myFunction()" href="javascript:void(0);"><div class="teksttilvideo">
    <?php echo __( '<img src="http://spectra-norge.no/wp-content/themes/spectranorge/img/spillavvideo_thumb.png" width="100%" class="tvshadow">'); ?>
    </div></a>
    <div class="tvshadow" id="videoholder" style="display:none;">
    <dd><?php echo(types_render_field('embedded-media-field', array("output" => "html"))); ?></dd>
    <?php }?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have checked and 'embedded-media-field' is not empty. And by removing the following:

```
<?php if(!empty(types_render_field('embedded-media-field', array('raw'=>'true')))){?>
    <a id="teksttilvideo" onclick="myFunction()" href="javascript:void(0);"><div class="teksttilvideo">
    <?php echo __( '<img src="http://spectra-norge.no/wp-content/themes/spectranorge/img/spillavvideo_thumb.png" width="100%" class="tvshadow">'); ?>
     </div></a>
```

And change `display:none` to `display:block`, the video shows up with no errors. However, the deleted part is important to the site.

The irony is that everything works perfectly fine on my other domain...

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What version of PHP was your old server and what is the new servers version?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. The old server has PHP Version 5.6, and I am trying to access cpanel on the new server, but it won't let me...

Comment: Execute the following. `$version = phpversion();
print $version;` and it will print your current version.

Comment: Reflush your permalinks

Comment: Thank you. It turns out my new server has PHP Version 5.4.38. Is that a big different...?

Comment: Turns out it could be the PHP Version as @Levi Zoesch mentioned. Source: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532693/weird-php-error-cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context). I am trying to change the PHP version with cPanel, but the "PHP Version" button is not available. I will post when I figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the PHP version mentioned by @Levi Zoesch.

The problem was that empty is not a *function*, but a *language construct* ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532693/weird-php-error-cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context)). The way I wrote it was supported by PHP 5.5+, and not older. Therefor the `fatal error` appeared.

To solve the problem I made a variable of the function:

```
<?php if(!empty(types_render_field('embedded-media-field', array('raw'=>'true')))){?>
```

Into:

```
<?php $renderfieldmedia = types_render_field('embedded-media-field', array('raw'=>'true'))?>
<?php if(!empty($renderfieldmedia)){?>
```

Problem solved.

Comment: Nice! Glad I was able to help :)