# Wordpress fatal error - Can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to upload a plugin on my WordPress site and I get the following error below:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context on line
>   491.

Here is the code that is in question. Any help is appreciated!

```
        if ( empty( get_post_meta( $order_id, '_sent_to_fba', true ) ) ) {
            return '';
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2173318/1714).  Try storing the result of the `get_post_meta()` call in a variable, then calling `empty()` using the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your php version.**Note:** 5.4.0   Checking non-numeric offsets of strings returns TRUE.If 5.5.0   empty() now supports expressions, rather than only variables.

```
$somevar = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_sent_to_fba', true );

  if(empty($somevar ))
  { return '';}
```

For more information please check this link 
**http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php**