# Login.php page won't display

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to set up a login system on my website. We will create the accounts on our end and then send the details over to the user.

When uploading all of the relevant php files to the server, the login.php page doesn't load and gives me HTTP ERROR 500.

login.php code:

```
?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = 'Please enter username.';
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
        $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session and save the username to the session
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;      
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = 'The password you entered was not valid.';
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = 'No account found with that username.';
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

After looking through the error logs it seems that the error lies within line 13 and 20, the error on the log reads "Can't use function return value in write context in"

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Have you googled that error message to learn what causes it?

Comment: As a side note: imho <?=$username_err?> looks better than <?php echo $username_err; ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this

```
!empty(trim($someText)) and doSomething()
```

> because empty is not a function but a language construct
>   , and it only takes variables:
>
> Right:
>
> ```
> empty($someVar)
> ```
>
> Wrong:
>
> ```
> empty(someFunc())
> ```

As stated here:

[Weird PHP error: 'Can't use function return value in write context'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532693/weird-php-error-cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context)

Also worth mentioning that `empty()` IS actually a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions (**prior to version 5.5)**.

So in your case, this: `empty(trim($_POST['username']))` won't work, you should use something like this: `trim($_POST['username']) == false`.

See documentation for more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: FYI, `empty()` has accepted expressions as valid input since 5.5.  So it's not quite as black and white as "right" and "wrong".  It depends on the version being used.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks for letting me know, although we didn't know which version he was using...

Comment: Well, we obviously know that it's lower than 5.5  :)

Comment: `empty()` **IS** a language construct (see documentation), which could be nice to add to your answer with the link.